# PCI-e Wireless Adapter T9E performing poorly when GPU is 100%. PCIe bottleneck or overheat?

Tags: wireless-networking, graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I'm running a Windows Desktop PC. I have dual GPU (GTX1080 PCI-E x16 and RX580 PCI-E x4). GTX1080 is used to drive display, while RX580 is purely for a specific computational GPU workload.

The Wireless adapter T9E was attached to the 2nd PCI-E x1 slot (physically located between the 2 GPUs). When RX580 is not in use, the wireless adapter T9E gets approx 70MBPS download (100MBPS connection). When the RX580 is on 100%, download drops to below 10MBPS.

Moving the T9E to the 1st PCI-E x1 slot (physically located next to the GTX1080), ties its performance to the GTX (PCI-E x16). When GTX is in 2D desktop use, T9E is getting full speed. When GTX is in 3D use, bandwidth drops to below 10 MBPS.

The Motherboard is [Asus Z-170P](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z170-P/HelpDesk_Manual/) which seems to suggest that the PCIEX1 do not share IRQ with the PCIEx16 (page 1-11). So I don't think this is a PCI-E bottleneck.

Another possibility is that the GPU causes the T9E to overheat.

Question:

1. How do I check for PCI-e bottleneck?
2. Does the T9E have a temperature sensor, if so, how can I get access to it? I'm using RealTemp for my temperature monitor.

Thank you

Comment: "Does the T9E have a temperature sensor?" - No;  Based on what you describe I would say, this is indeed a PCI-E bandwidth problem, the only two slots you have are two free PCI-e x1.

Comment: "the only two slots you have are two free PCI-e x1" I dont quite catch that. The T9E is in a PCI-e x1

Comment: Right; You indicated the card works normal in the x4 slot.

Comment: @Ramhound edited for clarity